# How to add boxes to a grid layout with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a grid layout where the top is message box and the bottom a horizontal box with 3 buttons. The code I'm using is this:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 

def on_button_clicked(b):
    print(b.text(), "was pressed.")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()

button1 = QPushButton("First")
button1.clicked.connect(lambda: on_button_clicked(button1))

button2 = QPushButton("Second")
button2.clicked.connect(lambda: on_button_clicked(button2))

button3 = QPushButton("Third")
button3.clicked.connect(lambda: on_button_clicked(button3))

top_box = QMessageBox()

bottom_box = QHBoxLayout()
bottom_box.addWidget(button1)
bottom_box.addWidget(button2)
bottom_box.addWidget(button3)

window = QGridLayout()
window.addWidget(top_box, 0, 0)
window.addWidget(bottom_box, 0, 1)

w.setLayout(window)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

No matter what though, it always outputs the following problem:

```
  addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QHBoxLayout'
  addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QHBoxLayout'
  addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QHBoxLayout'
```

Why it doesn't work? How can I make it work? Is it something basic about PyQt functionality that I'm just not getting or what? I'm really out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Why do you want to add a *dialog* to the layout of another widget? If your intention is to add more buttons, then that's a terribly wrong approach. Also, you cannot `addWidget(layout)`, since a layout is *not* a widget: if you want to add a layout, use [`addLayout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addLayout). But, as said above, you should not add a dialog to that layout in the first place.

Comment: Just trying things around. Seeing what can can't be done before progressing with the course lessons. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Ok, remember that dialogs (subclasses of QDialog, like QInputDialog) are intended to be *top level widgets* (windows), and should not be added to widgets (or layouts) as children objects, with a few specific exceptions (mdi areas, graphics views). Obviously, nobody forbids you to do it, but you do it at your own risk.

Comment: Yeah, I gotcha. Best practices and all that. Thank you for the advices.

Answer (score 0):

Change
window.addWidget(bottom_box, 0, 1)
to
window.addLayout(bottom_box, 0, 1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).